# Intellij IDEA: how to move cursor to Run configuration output console by keyboard

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

as the title said, how to move cursor to Run configuration output console by keyboard, I can focus on console by keyboard, but i can't turn page, to up/down, or to left/right.I wanna scroll.Anyone knows it? Thanks anyway~
Only using keyboard!

Comment: Do you mean the Run configuration output console or the Terminal tool window?

Comment: Run configuration output console, thx @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 0):

press alt + 4 to directly jump to output window in intelij